# How can I rotate a view on scroll event?

Tags: android

I want to rotate an `ImageView` with the same amount a finger is moved on screen and in the direction finger.
I am using

`public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)` of `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`.

I am detecting distance amount using Pythagoras' theorem.

`float rotationAmount = (float) Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);`

and then rotate the view by this amount like

`imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + rotationAmount);`

This works almost fine but it rotates the view clockwise for both clockwise and anti-clockwise gesture.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to rotate clockwise / anti-clockwise, just use `imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + rotationAmount);` or `imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() - rotationAmount);` depending on gestures

Comment: How to know if gesture is clockwise or anti clockwise ?

Comment: Take a look at onTouchEvent so. [link] (http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/05/animation-follow-touch-path.html) - here is an example how can you draw path. Just use the same approach and you will get user finger path. After this use a bit of geometry to decide is this clockwise/anti-clockwise direction

Comment: @MeanCoder if my answer helped you, please mark this as a solution